# Access request in Django forms Dynamic FileField.upload_to path

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using [this](http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2010/04/dynamic-file-upload-paths-in-django.html) article to create a dynamic path to save a file.  Is there anyway I can access the request object from within the `get_image_path` function as described in the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (clean) way to do this and I'd claim it's not a good idea anyway. I have no clue why you'd want the request in there, but keep in mind that many things on the request object can be tampered with by the user and using that to do filesystem operations can be unsafe.

However there is a way to do it, this method is frowned upon by most in the Django and Python community, but you can set a thread local in a middleware and access that in your function.

**middleware.py**:

```
import threading

mydata = threading.local()

class RequestHackMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        mydata.request = request
```

**models.py**:

```
from middleware import mydata

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    # do stuff with mydata.request
```